# Adding non empty validation in zend form

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

I have a misunderstanding about zend non empty validation. I am using following code for zend form to generate a `textarea`

```
 $this->addElement('textarea', 'comment', array(
       // 'label'      => 'Please Comment:',
        'required'   => false,
        'validators' => array('NotEmpty')
    ));
```

If I change `required` attribute to false then It works and values are not gone to database. But Problem is that if I set `requried=>true`, It shows the validation message even before submit of form soemthing like this `Value is required and can't be empty`.
Now What I want that this message shouldn't be shown before the form is submitted but validation of non empty should be implemented. Please guide where Am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you set *'required' => true* **Zend_Form** append in automatic the validator NotEmpty to input textarea. The error messages are displayed only if you execute the method of the **isValid()** Form.
Then calls the isValid the point that you feel most appropriate.